# How to SQL conver to dataframe

Tags: sql, python-3.x, dataframe

I want to convert to SQL to dataframe.\

```
SELECT day,
MAX(id),
MAX(if(device = 'Mobile devices with full browsers', 'mobile', 'pc')),
AVG(replace(replace(search_imprshare, '< 10%', '10'), '%', '') / 100),
REPLACE(SUBSTRING(SUBSTRING_INDEX(add_trackingcode, '_', 1), CHAR_LENGTH(SUBSTRING_INDEX(add_trackingcode, '_', 1 - 1)) + 2), add_trackingcode, '')
FROM MY_TEST_TABLE
GROUP BY day
```

But I can only do below that.
I don't know how to work on '???'.

```
df_data= df_data.groupby(['day').agg(
        {
            'id': np.max,
            'device ' : ???,
            'percent' : ???,
            'tracking' : ???
        }
    )
```

How should I do it?

Comment: Is it pandas? you can do e.g. `import pandas as pd` `df = pd.read_sql("""SELECT MAX(if(device = 'Mobile devices with full browsers', 'mobile', 'pc')) as device` <-- note the `as device` in the sql - your calculated columns don't have names in what you posted, which might make them a bit harder to work with.. Actually i think the output from your query will be generally hard to work with - why do you max the string of device? right now if any string in your table is not "Mobile devices with full browsers" then it'll say "pc" --> is it really what you want?

Comment: but i want do that as dataframe, not pd.read_sql
and i want that really